# ionCube Loader on Windows 64-bit running PHP 5.6.8 not working

Tags: php, version-control, php-5.6, ioncube

I have tried to configure ionCube Encoder on my Windows 10 PC running PHP 5.6.8 but without success. After downloading the encoder zip file from [ioCube Loaders](https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php)
I copied the "**ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll**" to "C:\xampp\php\ext". Then I updated my php.ini file to loaded the encoder

```
[ionCube Loader]
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll"
```

and restarted apache, but when I test it from then command prompt using "php -v", it does not load. See my result

```
php -v
Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll
PHP 5.6.8 (cli) (built: Apr 15 2015 15:07:09)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

I also tried setting it up using the loader-wizard, but it did not work too. Anyone with useful information will be of great help right now.
Thanks

Comment: What your apache error logs says?

Comment: Mismatching thread safe Loaders with non-ts PHP or vice versa, wrong word size, mismatched PHP versions or a location with insufficient privileges are common causes. Location and version look fine here. Best thing is to create a support ticket at https://support.ioncube.com if still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This Post is old but it might help other people. You have just to replace to dll. I had the same problem when using the 64bits dll. Replacing it with the x86 dll did the tric

Comment: Right. The word size has to match how PHP was built, and PHP for Windows from most providers, e.g. XAMPP, is 32 bit. Confusingly there have also been builds that are 64 bit but that operate as if they are 32 bit, using 32 bit longs rather than 64 bit. The ionCube Loader Wizard script has various detection methods and knowledge of special cases, and is recommended for help with installation.